Page break for a table within another table
I was creating a table with xltabular because my table is long and I need to make a page break, but in my table I need to put a list, which doesn't make a page break. Of course, I could break the list into two rows, but i have another column with a list too, so that white spaces are created.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{left= 2cm,
              right=2cm,
              top=2cm,
              bottom=2cm}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand\setrow[1]{\gdef\rowmac{#1}#1\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\clearrow{\global\let\rowmac\relax}
\clearrow

\NewDocumentCommand{\itemExt}{m o}{%%
    % Verificar el argumento opcional para determinar el nivel de itemize
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
        % Si hay un argumento opcional, se crea un segundo nivel
        \vspace*{-\baselineskip+5pt}
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}[topsep=5pt, partopsep=0pt, noitemsep, left=10pt, label= \textbullet]%
                \item #1%
            \end{itemize}%
        \end{minipage}
    }{%
        % Si no hay argumento opcional, solo un nivel
        \vspace*{-\baselineskip+5pt}
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}[topsep=5pt, partopsep=0pt, noitemsep, left=0pt]%
                \item #1%
            \end{itemize}%
        \end{minipage}
    }%
    %
}   

\usepackage{xparse} % Para manejar argumentos de comandos

% Definimos el comando \rellenarFila
\NewDocumentCommand{\rellenarFila}{m o m}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
        \def\totalCeldas{#1} % Si no se especifica total, usamos f como total.
    }{%
        \def\totalCeldas{#2} % Si se especifica t, lo usamos.
    }%
    % Generamos la fila
    \newcommand{\celda}{&} % Macro para separar celdas
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\totalCeldas}{%
        \ifnum\i<#1\celda % Celdas vacías hasta que toque rellenar
        \else\celda #3 % Relleno con el texto dado
        \fi%
    }%
    \\ % Final de la fila
}


\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{%
            @{}*{2}{p{0.18\textwidth}}
            X
            *{2}{p{0.18\textwidth}}
            X
        }
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{Delimitación}}} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Largo} & \textbf{Ancho} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Área}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Vértices}} \\
        
        \midrule
        
        100 m & 70 m & \multicolumn{2}{l}{7000 m\textsuperscript{2}} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\parbox{0.4\linewidth}{%
                \vspace*{5pt}
                zzzz \par
                zzzz \par
                zzzz \par
                zzzz \vspace*{5pt}}}  \\
        
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{Características de la zona}}} \\
        
        \arrayrulecolor{black}\cmidrule[0.9pt]{1-6}
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Suelo, relieve y clima}}  &  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Vegetación}} \\
        
        \midrule
        
        
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{Descripción del margen del río}}} \\
        %               
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Margen izquierdo}}  &  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Margen derecho}} \\
        %               
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{X}{En la parte alta, se observa una vegetación seca; mientras que en la parte baja la vegetación es más diversa, como la presencia de pastizales, alfalfa (\textit{Medicago sativa}), molle (\textit{Schinus molle}), eucalipto (\textit{Eucalyptus globulus}), \textit{Lobelia decurrens}, \textit{Cestrum parqui} y la presencia de actividades agrícolas sobre un suelo árido.}  &  
        \multicolumn{3}{X}{En la parte alta, la vegetación es xerófila con especies como \textit{Opuntia cilindrica}, \textit{Puya meziana Wittm} y \textit{Agave}, con presencia de formaciones rocosas y cactus característicos de suelos áridos. En la parte baja, la diversidad vegetal es escasa, destacando la presencia de \textit{Veronica anagallis-aquatica} y \textit{Cortaderia selloana} a lo largo del cauce del río, predominando un sustrato arenoso.} \\
        
        \multicolumn{3}{@{}X}{%
            \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
            \begin{itemize}[topsep=5pt,partopsep=0pt,noitemsep,left=0pt]
                \item \textbf{Sector 1: Zona de cultivos y andenes}
                \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
                    \item Comprende desde el inicio de la estación hasta el margen inicial del río.
                    \item Alberga extensas áreas de cultivo, donde se avistan lagartos en los caminos y canales de riego.
                    \item Predominan los andenes agrícolas y una cobertura significativa de pasto.                          
                    \item La vegetación incluye arbustos dispersos y, en algunas áreas, árboles pequeños hacia el límite con el Sector 2.
                    \item  Hábitat de reptiles y especies asociadas al uso agrícola y a los canales de riego.
                \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
        } &
        \multicolumn{3}{X}{%
            \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
            \begin{itemize}[topsep=5pt,partopsep=0pt,noitemsep,left=0pt]
                \item \textbf{Plantas vasculares desérticas:}
                \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
                    \item \textit{Trichocereus sp.}
                    \item Posiblemente \textit{Weberbauerocereus sp.}
                    \item \textit{Opuntia} (posiblemente \textit{O. cilindrica})
                    \item \textit{Puya meziana}
                    \item \textit{Agave sp.}
                \end{itemize}
                \item \textbf{Plantas vasculares ribereñas:}
                \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
                    \item \textit{Salix} (posiblemente \textit{S. humboldtiana})
                    \item \textit{Schinus molle}
                    \item \textit{Baccharis} (posiblemente \textit{B. salicifolia})
                    \item \textit{Cortaderia} (posiblemente \textit{selloana})
                    \item Posiblemente \textit{Freylinia sp.}
                    \item \textit{Epilobium sp.}
                \end{itemize}
                \item \textbf{Plantas vasculares acuáticas:}
                \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
                    \item \textit{Saggitaria sp.}
                    \item \textit{Equisetum} (posiblemente \textit{E. bogotense})
                    \item \textit{E. giganteum}
                    \item \textit{Juncus} (posiblemente \textit{J. arcticus})
                    \item \textit{Zannichellia} (posiblemente \textit{Z. andina})
                    \item \textit{Cotula coronopifolia}
                    \item \textit{Veronica anagallis-aquatica}
                \end{itemize}
                \item \textbf{Algas:}
                \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
                    \item \textit{Ulva} (posiblemente \textit{U. intestinalis})
                    \item \textit{Cladophora sp.}
                \end{itemize}                                           
            \end{itemize}
        } \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{xltabular}
    
    \clearpage
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{%
            @{}*{2}{p{0.18\textwidth}}
            X
            *{2}{p{0.18\textwidth}}
            X
        }
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{Delimitación}}} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Largo} & \textbf{Ancho} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Área}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Vértices}} \\
        
        \midrule
        
        100 m & 70 m & \multicolumn{2}{l}{7000 m\textsuperscript{2}} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\parbox{0.4\linewidth}{%
                \vspace*{5pt}
                zzzz \par
                zzzz\par
                zzzz\par
                zzzzzzzz \vspace*{5pt}}}  \\
        
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{Características de la zona}}} \\
        
        \arrayrulecolor{black}\cmidrule[0.9pt]{1-6}
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Suelo, relieve y clima}}  &  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Vegetación}} \\
        
        \midrule
        
        
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{Descripción del margen del río}}} \\
        %               
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Margen izquierdo}}  &  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Margen derecho}} \\
        %               
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{X}{En la parte alta, se observa una vegetación seca; mientras que en la parte baja la vegetación es más diversa, como la presencia de pastizales, alfalfa (\textit{Medicago sativa}), molle (\textit{Schinus molle}), eucalipto (\textit{Eucalyptus globulus}), \textit{Lobelia decurrens}, \textit{Cestrum parqui} y la presencia de actividades agrícolas sobre un suelo árido.}  &  
        \multicolumn{3}{X}{En la parte alta, la vegetación es xerófila con especies como \textit{Opuntia cilindrica}, \textit{Puya meziana Wittm} y \textit{Agave}, con presencia de formaciones rocosas y cactus característicos de suelos áridos. En la parte baja, la diversidad vegetal es escasa, destacando la presencia de \textit{Veronica anagallis-aquatica} y \textit{Cortaderia selloana} a lo largo del cauce del río, predominando un sustrato arenoso.} \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{X}{\itemExt{\textbf{Sector 1: Zona de cultivos y andenes}}} &   \multicolumn{3}{X}{\itemExt{\textbf{Plantas vasculares desérticas}}} \\
        
        \multicolumn{3}{X}{\itemExt{Comprende desde el inicio de la estación hasta el margen inicial del río.}[-]} &    \multicolumn{3}{X}{\itemExt{\textit{Trichocereus sp.}}[-]} \\
        
        \multicolumn{3}{X}{\itemExt{Alberga extensas áreas de cultivo, donde se avistan lagartos en los caminos y canales de riego}[-]} &   \multicolumn{3}{X}{\itemExt{Posiblemente \textit{Weberbauerocereus sp.}}[-]} \\
        
        \multicolumn{3}{X}{\itemExt{Predominan los andenes agrícolas y una cobertura significativa de pasto.}[-]} &     \multicolumn{3}{X}{\itemExt{Opuntia (posiblemente O. cilindrica)}[-]} \\
        
        
        \bottomrule
    \end{xltabular}
    
    
\end{document}


As you can see, the row with the list makes a page break and I would like that when a list reaches the end of the page, it goes to the next page. Another approach I had was to create a command that makes an element and introduces it row by row so that the pages break when a row ends, but the problem now is the blank spaces caused by the different widths between rows:

Well, what I want to achieve is something similar to what is in the first figure but without the white space created and I don't know if that is possible. I would appreciate your help. Thank you in advance :D

you can't break a cell/row across pages. you can only have breaks between rows. so, if I've understood what you're asking correctly then, no, that's not possible. that's not to say the problem can't be solved. but it cannot be solved in that way. if you only have one or two such cases, you are probably best splitting them manually when the rest of the document is finalised.

Off-topic: left= 2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm may be expressed more succinctly as margin=2cm.

The problem is not actually the itemize-type list environment, but the fact that you're encasing the list in a minipage environment. Can you make do without the minipage wrapper?

I can't read the text but this doesn't like a data table, it looks as you are misusing a tabular to get a two column layout. Perhaps you should better use multicol.

Your setup is really confusing: You define the xltabular environmen to have six columns, yet you never actually make use of them. Instead, you provide lots and lots of \mutlicolumn wrappers that completely override the basic table setup.

I agree with @UlrikeFischer's comment that this table is not well designed. Whatever is in the left-hand column appears to be unrelated to what's in the right-hand column, and vice versa. Do give the matter of proper layout some more thought.
If you decide to keep the xltabular setup, please simplify it drastically. E.g., don't define the xltabular environment to have 6 columns when it only needs 2. Also, please don't overdo EMPHASIZING the headers. Bold and all-uppercase? You may also want to consider adding underlining. :-) Seriously, over-emphasis quickly switches into the baroque.
Maybe something more like this? Note that I've added possible \endfirsthead, \endhead, \endfoot, and \endlastfoot directives in order to make actually make use of the machinery of the xltabular package.

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\fi
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{xltabular,microtype,booktabs,enumitem}
\usepackage{array,cellspace,lipsum,calc,xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for '\qty' macro

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} XX @{}}

%% headers and footers
\caption{Place caption text here}\\
\toprule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\tablename~\thetable, continued}\\ % how to say this in Spanish?
\addlinespace
\toprule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{\footnotesize(continued on next page)}\\ % how to say this in Spanish?
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot


%% body of table
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Delimitación} \\
\midrule

\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{@{} XXX @{}}
  Largo & Ancho & Área
\end{tabularx}
& Vértices \\
    
\midrule

\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{@{} XXX @{}}
  \qty{100}{\meter} & 
  \qty{70}{\meter} & 
  \qty{7000}{\meter\squared} 
\end{tabularx} & 
zzzz \par zzzz \par zzzz \par zzzz \\
   
   
\addlinespace 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Características de la zona}\\
\midrule

Suelo, relieve y clima & Vegetación \\
    
\addlinespace
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Descripción del margen del río} \\         
\midrule

\addlinespace
Margen izquierdo & Margen derecho \\ 
\addlinespace

En la parte alta, se observa una vegetación seca; mientras que en la parte baja la vegetación es más diversa, como la presencia de pastizales, alfalfa (\textit{Medicago sativa}), molle (\textit{Schinus molle}), eucalipto (\textit{Eucalyptus globulus}), \textit{Lobelia decurrens}, \textit{Cestrum parqui} y la presencia de actividades agrícolas sobre un suelo árido. &  
En la parte alta, la vegetación es xerófila con especies como \textit{Opuntia cilindrica}, \textit{Puya meziana Wittm} y \textit{Agave}, con presencia de formaciones rocosas y cactus característicos de suelos áridos. En la parte baja, la diversidad vegetal es escasa, destacando la presencia de \textit{Veronica anagallis-aquatica} y \textit{Cortaderia selloana} a lo largo del cauce del río, predominando un sustrato arenoso. \\

\midrule

  Sector 1: Zona de cultivos y andenes
  \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,left=0pt]
  \item Comprende desde el inicio de la estación hasta el margen inicial del río.
  \item Alberga extensas áreas de cultivo, donde se avistan lagartos en los caminos y canales de riego.
  \item Predominan los andenes agrícolas y una cobertura significativa de pasto.              
  \item La vegetación incluye arbustos dispersos y, en algunas áreas, árboles pequeños hacia el límite con el Sector~2.
  \item Hábitat de reptiles y especies asociadas al uso agrícola y a los canales de riego.
  \end{itemize}
 &
  Plantas vasculares desérticas
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
      \item \textit{Trichocereus sp.}
      \item Posiblemente \textit{Weberbauerocereus sp.}
      \item \textit{Opuntia} (posiblemente \textit{O. cilindrica})
      \item \textit{Puya meziana}
      \item \textit{Agave sp.}
    \end{itemize}
    
    Plantas vasculares ribereñas
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
      \item \textit{Salix} (posiblemente \textit{S. humboldtiana})
      \item \textit{Schinus molle}
      \item \textit{Baccharis} (posiblemente \textit{B. salicifolia})
      \item \textit{Cortaderia} (posiblemente \textit{selloana})
      \item Posiblemente \textit{Freylinia sp.}
      \item \textit{Epilobium sp.}
    \end{itemize}\\ % allow a page break at this point

    &
    Plantas vasculares acuáticas
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
      \item \textit{Saggitaria sp.}
      \item \textit{Equisetum} (posiblemente \textit{E. bogotense})
      \item \textit{E. giganteum}
      \item \textit{Juncus} (posiblemente \textit{J. arcticus})
      \item \textit{Zannichellia} (posiblemente \textit{Z. andina})
      \item \textit{Cotula coronopifolia}
      \item \textit{Veronica anagallis-aquatica}
    \end{itemize}
    
    Algas
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
      \item \textit{Ulva} (posiblemente \textit{U. intestinalis})
      \item \textit{Cladophora sp.}
    \end{itemize}                       
 \\

\end{xltabular}
  
\end{document}


I agree with @UlrikeFischer's comment that this table is not well designed too. Instead of xltabular  package I would rather use longtblr of tabularray package. Using it the table code is simpler and shorter, however a cost for this is longer compilation time.
For starting point of MWE below is used nice @Mico answer (+1):
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{microtype,
            enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,
                siunitx,    % for '\qty' macro
                varwidth}   % for lists
    \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{(Continued on next page)}
    \SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begingroup
    \setlist{nosep, topsep=3pt, itemsep=1pt, leftmargin=1.5em}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Place caption text here},
  label = {longtab:whatever}
                ]{colspec = {@{} *{2}{X[font=\linespread{0.9}\relax]} @{} },
                  stretch = -1,%<--- remove extra space above and below lists
                               % with nosep option; doc p.51 tabularray
                   measure = vbox,
                   rowsep  = 3pt,
                   rowhead = 1
                  }  
    \toprule
\SetCell[c=2]{c}    Delimitación
    &           \\
    \midrule
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} XXX @{}},
             rowsep  = 1pt}
Largo   &   Ancho   &   Área
\end{tblr}
    &   Vértices                                    \\
    \midrule
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} XXX @{}},
             rowsep  = 1pt}
\qty{100}{\meter} 
    &   \qty{70}{\meter} 
        &   \qty{7000}{\meter\squared}
\end{tblr} 
    &    {zzzz\\    zzzz\\  zzzz\\  zzzz}           \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[c=2]{c}   Características de la zona
    &                                               \\
    \midrule
Suelo, relieve y clima 
    & Vegetación                                    \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[c=2]{}    Descripción del margen del río
    &                                               \\
    \midrule
Margen izquierdo 
    &   Margen derecho                                \\

En la parte alta, se observa una vegetación seca; mientras que en la parte baja la vegetación es más diversa, como la presencia de pastizales, alfalfa (\textit{Medicago sativa}), molle (\textit{Schinus molle}), eucalipto (\textit{Eucalyptus globulus}), \textit{Lobelia decurrens}, \textit{Cestrum parqui} y la presencia de actividades agrícolas sobre un suelo árido.
    &   En la parte alta, la vegetación es xerófila con especies como \textit{Opuntia cilindrica}, \textit{Puya meziana Wittm} y \textit{Agave}, con presencia de formaciones rocosas y cactus característicos de suelos áridos. En la parte baja, la diversidad vegetal es escasa, destacando la presencia de \textit{Veronica anagallis-aquatica} y \textit{Cortaderia selloana} a lo largo del cauce del río, predominando un sustrato arenoso. \\
    \midrule
Sector 1: Zona de cultivos y andenes
  \begin{itemize}
\item Comprende desde el inicio de la estación hasta el margen inicial del río.
\item Alberga extensas áreas de cultivo, donde se avistan lagartos en los caminos y canales de riego.
\item Predominan los andenes agrícolas y una cobertura significativa de pasto.
\item La vegetación incluye arbustos dispersos y, en algunas áreas, árboles pequeños hacia el límite con el Sector~2.
\item Hábitat de reptiles y especies asociadas al uso agrícola y a los canales de riego.
  \end{itemize}
    &   Plantas vasculares desérticas
        \begin{itemize}
    \item \textit{Trichocereus sp.}
    \item Posiblemente \textit{Weberbauerocereus sp.}
    \item \textit{Opuntia} (posiblemente \textit{O. cilindrica})
    \item \textit{Puya meziana}
    \item \textit{Agave sp.}
        \end{itemize}

    \medskip
   Plantas vasculares ribereñas
        \begin{itemize}
      \item \textit{Salix} (posiblemente \textit{S. humboldtiana})
      \item \textit{Schinus molle}
      \item \textit{Baccharis} (posiblemente \textit{B. salicifolia})
      \item \textit{Cortaderia} (posiblemente \textit{selloana})
      \item Posiblemente \textit{Freylinia sp.}
      \item \textit{Epilobium sp.}
        \end{itemize}           \\ % allow a page break at this point

    &   Plantas vasculares acuáticas
        \begin{itemize}
    \item \textit{Saggitaria sp.}
    \item \textit{Equisetum} (posiblemente \textit{E. bogotense})
    \item \textit{E. giganteum}
    \item \textit{Juncus} (posiblemente \textit{J. arcticus})
    \item \textit{Zannichellia} (posiblemente \textit{Z. andina})
    \item \textit{Cotula coronopifolia}
    \item \textit{Veronica anagallis-aquatica}
        \end{itemize}

    \medskip
        Algas
        \begin{itemize}
    \item \textit{Ulva} (posiblemente \textit{U. intestinalis})
    \item \textit{Cladophora sp.}
        \end{itemize}               \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}


